# Regular Expression - Start with 3538 and then contain 8 digits

Tags: regex

E.g. match 353812345678 So far I have ^3538{1}[\d]{8} which works but does not restrict the length. How do I make sure the length is only a maximum of 12 digits?

Comment: Bear in mind that will match if for instance the string only contains `353812345678` but it won't match `353812345678 abc` (which is valid from what I can understand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a dollar sign ($) at the end of the regex:
    ^3538{1}[\d]{8}$

Answer (score 4):

If you want the number to be the only thing in the string: `^3538\d{8}$`

If you just want the number in a string: `\b3538\d{8}\b`

`^` is the start-of-string anchor, while `$` is the [end-of-string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), so the first one restricts the number to be the only thing on the line.

In the other one, `\b` means a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), so it just means no other letters or digits may come directly before or after the number.

Also, note, in your original regex, the `{1}` is redundant, and `[\d]` means the same as `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

`^3538{1}[\d]{8}[^\d]` will ensure you have 3538 followed by 8 digits and something that is NOT a digit -- thus limiting the length.